# MySQL Prefix index And Covering index (Full index )

Tags: mysql, indexing

When i use mysql-5.7.17, I found something.
I use Innodb And charst: utf8.

Covering index table schema:

`CREATE TABLE test_table (
  c_pk varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  c_default varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  c_notnull varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (c_pk),
  KEY IDX_test_table (c_notnull)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Prefix index table schema:

`CREATE TABLE ntable (
  c_pk varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  c_default varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  c_notnull varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (c_pk(10)),
  KEY IDX_test_table (c_notnull(10))
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

And Insert same data to ntable and test_table
(Data has number and multi byte characters: ex - 123, 한글)
When i execute select query like: SELECT * FROM ntable WHERE c_notnull LIKE '윤선중윤선중윤선중윤선중윤선중윤선중%';

Tables result is difference.
select data is same but the order is different.

Originally MySQL Prefix index And Covering index(Full index) results is different??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an `ORDER BY`, the engine is free to deliver the rows in any order it chooses.  To discover what order the results will *probably* be in, we need to dig into the implementation:

In the first case `KEY IDX_test_table (c_notnull)` is a BTree ordered first by `c_notnull`, then by `c_pk` since the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly appended to every secondary key.

In the second case, the index is effectively `(LEFT(c_notnull, 10), c_pk)`.  The characters after the 10th are not involved in the order.

Try these to see if my analysis is correct:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY c_notnull, c_pk;            -- expect it to match case 1
SELECT ... ORDER BY LEFT(c_notnull, 10), c_pk;  -- expect it to match case 2
```

It is very rare for a "prefix" index to be useful.  I recommend you avoid it unless `c_notnull` is too long (eg, `TEXT`) to allow a full index.

When the order matters, use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it to use ORDER BY c_notnull, c_pk.